# Website is indexing non secure url only on ie and edge

Tags: redirect

I got a message from a client saying that they have the error screen.
There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.

I know the reason why but don't know how to resolve it, the website is https://kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk/ this is the url with the secure certificate on when i google "kingsley recruitment" in chrome and other browsers it presents this url but when i google "kingsley recruitment" in ie/edge it presents https://www.kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk/

Is there a redirect i could do to redirect users to the secure url ?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup isn't well. You should have www.kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk and kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk in your certificate (both in SAN section, CN can be any of these).

A redirect to other alias is ONLY possible with a valid certificate for both domains. Of course you can always redirect port 80 to 443, but not 443 to 443 without certificate (or any other ports using certificates).

Answer (score 0):

As @Rainer says, add www.kingslayrecruitment.co.uk to you cretificate in SAN (Subject Alternative Name) and use it for that vhost because now you provide somting strange - *.gear.host

```
% openssl s_client -connect www.kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk:443 2>/dev/null | grep subject
subject=/C=US/ST=CO/L=Englewood/O=GearHost Inc./CN=*.gear.host
```

If you use certbot for letsencrypt just type multiple domains separated by comas

Then visitors on www.kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk got proper certificate and can trust your redirect to kingsleyrecruitment.co.uk